# Cloned Github project, but can't resolve AppCompat themes

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am trying to clone this GitHub project:
https://github.com/NielsMasdorp/Speculum-Android

When I run it I get several errors:

```
Error:(3, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\Android Projects\Speculum-Android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.

Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\Android Projects\Speculum-Android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.

Error:(6, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\Android Projects\Speculum-Android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.

Error:(10, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\Android Projects\Speculum-Android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat'.
```

All of the errors are in the `styles.xml`, can someone clone it and tell me what I need to do to get rid of these errors?

style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

<style name="InputLayout" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

new errors:

```
Error:(83, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable static_maps_api_key
Error:(43, 8) error: dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
:app:compileRetrolambdaDebug
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: You really should share your `res\values\styles.xml` with an [edit].

Comment: The code *should* run fine. The [appcompat themes](https://github.com/NielsMasdorp/Speculum-Android/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L48)  are included in the Gradle file and [the styles.xml has those attributes](https://github.com/NielsMasdorp/Speculum-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml)  that you are missing

Comment: Please [edit] the question. Code does not belong in the comments.

Comment: just added my style.xml to the original post thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Have you downloaded the respective SDK for the project from the SDK Manager?

Comment: Right now i am using android API 23 Platform (java version "1.8.0_101")

Comment: Could you just run me through what you did step by step and ill just follow that and hopefully it work. Much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "what I did"? I get an error myself when I build. `R.string.static_maps_api_key` cannot be resolved. I don't have a Google Maps API key

Comment: like what jdk youre running and i don't plan on using the google maps API key so i was just going to delete that code

Comment: also i began to have a problem when i try to clone i get "SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable"

Comment: Yeah, that always happens to me. You have to provide a `local.properties` file. I just copy from another project.

Comment: Once I fix the XML problem, then the linter is complaining about Java 8 and Retrolambda, which I've never used. All in all, I am not seeing the styles.xml error that you have referenced.

Comment: yeah i think i have the style.xml thing figured out. It just won't run on my device when i try to run

Comment: You are welcome to edit the question again to rephrase with the current problems.

Comment: i get these 3 errors now:

Comment: Again, please [edit] the question with that information

Comment: i did sorry i keep forgetting

Comment: `cannot find symbol variable static_maps_api_key` -- So, yeah, did you read the README of that project that said add the `keys.xml`?

Comment: i got it to work! thanks man

Comment: Welcome. All I basically said was to read the documentation ;)